# error: "the method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Square)

Tags: java, swing

I have the above-named problem - I wonder if there are any experts who can help.

1. Component is an item I have imported from java.awt API
2. I do not know where Eclipse derived the "Container" from!!
3. In the Qs I searched, the place where it says (Square) after "arguments", it has a data type in other people's Qs - in mine it is a class that is in the same package as the one below, in which the error appears in line 19 "choras.add(trial);", so I assume the class is being detected as a type.

CODE:

```
package square;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class SquareTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Square trial = new Square(12);
        {
            JFrame choras = new JFrame();

            choras.setSize(300, 430);
            choras.setTitle("Hi iko square yangu");
            choras.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            choras.add(trial);

            choras.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> the method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Square)

[`javax.swing.JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) extends [`java.awt.Frame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) extends [`java.awt.Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) extends [`java.awt.Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), therefore, `JFrame` is a type of `Container`.

[`Container#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) expects an object that extends from [`java.awt.Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

Presumably, `Square` does not extend from any class that inherits from (directly or indirectly) `java.awt.Component`, but seen as you've not provided us with that class, we can only guess...

Comment: I include the Dquare class here:

Comment: package square;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Square {

 private double sideLength;
 private double area;
 
 public Square(int initialLength)
 {
  sideLength = initialLength;
  area = sideLength * sideLength;
  
 }
 public double getArea()
 {
  return area;
 }
 public void grow()
 {
  sideLength = 2 * sideLength;
  
 }
}
It is clear now that I amtrying to execute a calculation file instead of a graphics file - thanks very much for pointing out this simple "error" (actually it is absent-mindedness - ADVICE: avoid becoming 30+ in age!!)

Comment: `public class Square {` <-- Doesn't `extend` from directly or indirectly from `java.awt.Component` ... *"avoid becoming 30+ in age"* to late - better advice, just don't grow up ;)

Comment: Try `public class Square extends JPanel {` instead

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite Obvious[**Jframe.add(Component)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) expects a [**java.awt.Component**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) as an argument and you are passing a **Square** to it, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that you cannot add a Shape to a JFrame. (You can read about containers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483533/java-swing-custom-shapes-2d-graphics) may be of use to you if you are looking to use custom shapes in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Square` class, make sure you are extending/implementing something:

```
public class Square extends JPanel
```