# How to Produce Physical Dimension of an Image drawn using Java

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I have drawn a square on JPanel in Swing Applet.now i want to print this **square having physical dimension 50cm * 50 cm  on to paper.it means the print measurement of the square is 50 * 50 cm in real world which i drawn on to panel of an applet** .the printer uses **400 DPI** to print.

so how can i relate these to measurements ?
in which file format i should save my drawing so it will have accurate measurement while printing , equals to printer DPI and quality of the image is maintained in print.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert you centimeter value to inches, so you can obtain the Dots Per Inch

1 cm = 0.393700787 inches
50 cm * 0.393700787 inches = 19.68503935 inches
19.68503935 * 400 = 7874.01574 pixels

Comment: As [requested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2483977/230513), I can verify that Mad's calculation recapitulates that of MrSmith42. I'm not sure what I can add.

Answer (score 2):

50cm with 400 DPI are:
50/2,54*400 = 7874 Pixels
I recommend **png** or **gif** (gif only for <= 255 colors)

Comment: how do you come up with pixels number ? what formula you used ? i think you did not get my question yet ? thanks